# export php to excel with separate column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to export my database to .csv   the exporting done ,but it put all the fields
in one column (without separating)

the code :

```
$sql = "SELECT ARP_name ,Student_name   ,institute  ,id ,Major from       istyle ";
$results=mysql_query($sql);
$filename = "uploaded/".time().".csv";

$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');

fputcsv($handle, array_keys("ARP_name","Student_name","institute"));

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    fputcsv($handle, array($row["ARP_name"], $row["Student_name"],$row["institute"]));
}
```

the result is :

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your csv export looks perfectly fine on first glance I assume you mean that the spreadsheet you are trying to import the data into puts everything into one single column?

There are various settings you can adjust to describe the csv format details when importing data into spreadsheet applications. Check the applications preferences dialog. OpenOffice and LibreOffice Calc applications come with a great wizard for this.

Comment: yes, it puts them in one column
I mean  ARP_name in column, id in another column..etc

Comment: So, what improvement did you get when ajusting the import parameters as suggested? I _guess_ the spreadsheet uses a semicolon (`;`) as default separator character, not the comma (`,`).

Comment: the excel sheet will be in order

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that. You mean you solved the problem?

Comment: No ,I don't .
when I put ; instead of , I get this error 

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: Why a php error? I though we are talking about the import of a file into a spreadsheet. That is nothing to do with php... Where did you do that adjustment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20432/discussion-between-arkascha-and-norah)

Answer (score 0):

For separate columns use ' \t ' for separate rows use ' \n '